# How can I check one package direct depends / indirect depends on another?

Tags: go, dependencies

## As titled.

My solution would be

```
cd $PATH_4_PACKAGE_ONE
go list -f '{{ join .Deps "\n" }}' | grep "$PATH_4_PACKAGE_TWO"
```

1. Is there a better solution?
2. What if I want find packages in an list of packages depends on any packages from another list of packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use go modules to magnage your dependencies

```
> go init # initialize go modules 
> go mod download # download dependencies
```

now you had `go.mod` file, it included all the dependencies from your go project

```
> cat go.mod | egrep -v "(indirect)|(^\module)|(require)|(\))" # list all direct dependencies
> cat go.mod | egrep "indirect" # list all indirect dependencies
```

Comment: good tool and good feature for go1.11. But, how can I use it to solve my problem? Your answer seams to print dependencies of project.

Comment: then you can switch package directory, do then same thing what i just tell you, after you get what you want, remove `go.mod` & `go.sum`

Comment: Rule of GO111MODULE in 'go help mod' gives me some pain, because our project is under GOPATH for history reason. Do you use 'go mod' for your project, it seams to be designed for go project outside of GOPATH?

Comment: `export GO111MODULE=on`, go modules will not open as default, you have to manually open it by set env, no matter it's gopath object or not, once you had go file in your directory, you can generate go.mod by go modules commands