# How to determine which module/s use an indirect dependency?

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules

In Go 1.17 go.mod has two sections, direct dependencies and indirect dependencies, however, there is no indication how indirect dependencies are related to direct dependencies.

How can I find out for a particuar indirect dependency what module or modules use it?

Comment: Note that this isn't new in Go 1.17. Indirect dependencies always existed in go.mod, they were just moved to a new section in Go 1.17.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57159707/13860

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`go mod why -m $MODULE` will give you one (arbitrarily-chosen) chain of imports from a package in your module to a package in `$MODULE`. However, it does not natively report all such paths.

`go list -json all` does expose enough information to identify those paths, but it does not provide an easy way to present import chains for human consumption. However, some third-party tools (such as [`goda`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/loov/goda) and [`gomod`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Helcaraxan/gomod)) can transform or query the output from `go list` with more structure. (See their documentation for query syntax and examples.)

Comment: Is `go mod graph` an acceptable alternative?

Comment: Not really, no. A module dependency is only added to the `// indirect` section if some package is imported from it, but `go mod graph` doesn't examine the package import graph at all — it only reports the dependencies between modules, not the packages within those modules.

Comment: In other words: `go mod graph` will give you a conservative approximation. (It will report some module-to-module edges that result from packages that aren't actually relevant to your program.)

Comment: Relevant, but perhaps not as useful to the OP's intent in asking the question. They're asking “for a particuar indirect dependency what module or modules use it”, but for the `indirect` modules in the `go.mod` file the only uses that really matter are packages transitively imported by the main module. It really depends on which question they're trying to answer: `go mod graph` answers “why this particular version?”, while the package-import graph answers “why this module at all?”.